# Cloud9 custom 404 page

Tags: html, apache2, http-status-code-404, cloud9-ide

I'm currently using Cloud9 to build a website.
Now, I was wondering if I could set my own 404 not found page.
I tried using a .htaccess file with the code `ErrorDocument 404 /404.html` in it.
Also, I tried using this command in the commandline at the bottom of the screen, when you run the app (website).
Anyone has any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ErrorDocument directive you listed should basically do it. Follow these steps:

1. Create a file .htaccess in your workspace directory. Contents: `ErrorDocument 404 /404.html`
2. Create a file 404.html in your workspace directory. Contents: `Hi mom!`
3. Type `run-apache2` in the terminal, or use the "Run Project" button if your project is setup to use Apache by default
4. Ask your mom to open `https://`*workspace*`-`*username*`.c9.io/bla`. Watch her reaction.